# Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [long list] (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to deploy a Jekyll site on a remote server via `bundler`. Here's what I've done:

- `gem install jekyll bundler` works.
- `bundle --version` says `bundle` isn't a command, so I poked added and found that it was installed in `$HOME/ruby/gems/bin`, then added that to my path.
- Now, when I run `bundle --version`, I get:

  ```
  /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-2.3.14, actionpack-2.3.14, activerecord-2.3.14, activeresource-2.3.14, activesupport-2.3.14, cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0, daemon_controller-0.2.6, daemons-1.1.4, fastthread-1.0.7, gem_plugin-0.2.3, mongrel-1.1.5, passenger-3.0.9, rack-1.1.2, rails-2.3.14, rake-0.9.2.2, rmagick-2.12.2, rubygems-update-1.8.11, sqlite3-1.3.4] (Gem::LoadError)
      from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
      from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
      from /home/udallashosting/ruby/gems/bin/bundle:18
  ```
- `gem list bundler` outputs `bundler (1.14.6)`, among many others.
- Tried some alternatives: neither `bundle` nor `rubygems-bundler` installs successfully.

I know almost nothing about Ruby.

Comment: You really want a new version of ruby than anything in the 1.8 series.

Comment: @rposborne Ugh... can I install that as user, or should I make a request to my provider?

Comment: If you are using jekyll to build a static site I would highly recommend using it locally versus trying to run it on something that you have to request to install things. Once you have the site built it is trival to copy the compiled site into a basic web host.

Comment: @rposborne But if I do it this way, I can (hopefully) set up a webhook on GitHub to automatically deploy my site on push.

Comment: There are other ways to achieve that will give you more control of the process.  I personally use tools like travis-ci or wercker handle the webhook, do the build then copy the static site to wherever it needs to go.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `bundler --version` ?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I tried both. Same output.